# Subtract two query results in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 queries which gives all records(including the booked ones) and gives out booked records only. I wanted to subtract the two tables so that it only shows the unbooked records, here are the example of the query results:

Query 1:

```
+--------+--------+
| Number | AreaNo | 
+--------+--------+ 
|      6 |      A |  
|      6 |      B |  
|      6 |      C |  
|      7 |      A | 
|      7 |      B | 
+--------+--------+
```

Query 2:

```
+--------+--------+
| Number | AreaNo | 
+--------+--------+ 
|      6 |      B |  
|      6 |      C |   
|      7 |      B | 
+--------+--------+
```

Desired Results:

```
+--------+--------+
| Number | AreaNo | 
+--------+--------+ 
|      6 |      A |  
|      7 |      A | 
|      7 |      C | 
+--------+--------+
```

I know that I can't use MINUS in mySQL but I'm not sure that LEFT JOIN works in this situation. If this doesn't work, is it possible to work on the where clause?(Like if the number match, it only clear out the one with matching AreaNo). I tried this with two AND clause and it doesn't work. It clears out the results that doesnt fit either criteria. I have been doing researches over a week and nothing works. Please help, I am  really desperated.

Query 1:

```
SELECT bookingListNo,
       areaNo 
  FROM BookingList, 
       BookingArea, 
       BookingLocation 
 WHERE bookingListNo NOT IN (SELECT bookingListNo 
                               FROM Booking 
                              WHERE bookingAreaNo IS NULL) AND 
       BookingList.bookingLocationNo = BookingLocation.bookingLocationNo AND
       BookingLocation.BookingLocationNo = BookingArea.bookingLocationNo
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT bookingListNo, 
       areaNo 
  FROM Booking, 
       BookingArea 
 WHERE Booking.bookingAreaNo = BookingArea.bookingAreaNo
```

Comment: Could you show your query?

Comment: The answer I posted actually gives you 6A and 7A.  It does not give you 7C.  Are you looking for that too?

Comment: Thanks for your help @SQLDBA. Your suggestion works.
And this is my query:
Query 1:

SELECT bookingListNo,areaNo
FROM BookingList, BookingArea,BookingLocation
WHERE bookingListNo NOT IN (SELECT bookingListNo FROM Booking WHERE bookingAreaNo IS NULL)
AND BookingList.bookingLocationNo  = BookingLocation.bookingLocationNo
AND BookingLocation.BookingLocationNo = BookingArea.bookingLocationNo

Query 2:
SELECT bookingListNo, areaNo
FROM Booking, BookingArea
WHERE Booking.bookingAreaNo = BookingArea.bookingAreaNo

Once again, thanks for all your help1

Comment: IS THE LAST 7C REALLY REQUIRED??

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it.

```
   SELECT Q1.Number, 
          Q1.AreaNo
     FROM Query1 Q1 
LEFT JOIN Query2 Q2 
       ON Q1.Number = Q2.Number AND
          Q1.AreaNo = Q2.AreaNo
    WHERE Q2.Number IS NULL AND
          Q2.AreaNo IS NULL
```

Comment: FYI: There's no need to check `Number` *and* `AreaNo` if both can't be NULL.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Just check one or the other...I always check all.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article for reference: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

I'm guessing a RIGHT JOIN would do the trick.

Not exactly sure what your tables are like, but if you are joining a table with unbooked data to one that has all of our items, then you could do a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM all_items
RIGHT JOIN unbooked_data ON all_items.item_id = unbooked_data.item_id
```

When you RIGHT JOIN it only selects the items that are in the table you are joining on that have matches in the table being joined to. This should allow you to select unbooked data. If this doesn't fit your situation, including your queries in your question might help us answer your problem more directly.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` will do the trick

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE1 t_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t_2 
       ON t_1.AreaNo = t_2.AreaNo ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT tabl1.number,tabl1.areano FROM tabl1 LEFT JOIN tabl2 using(number,
areano) WHERE tabl2.number IS NULL; ;
+--------+--------+
| number | areano |
+--------+--------+
|      6 | A      |
|      7 | A      |
+--------+--------+
```